# GeoCoder with IOException

Tags: android

Actually Im finding the latitude and longitude for the address but max time getting java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for response from server,the emulator i use base on API 19 with Google API,any body can offer some help?
thanks,here is my source code

```
   Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), 
   Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, 
   longitude, 1);
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {

   stringBuilder.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                stringBuilder.append(address.getLocality()).append("_");
                stringBuilder.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("_");
                stringBuilder.append(address.getCountryCode()).append("_");
                stringBuilder.append(address.getCountryName()).append("_");
                Log.i(tag, stringBuilder.toString());
            } else {
                ToastUtil.show(getApplicationContext(), "无效地址");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Could you have a chance to try it with a physical device , cuz emulators not efficient for physical things.

Comment: yes,i tried on a real device later,and there is no exception,but i can not get the info of street,only the locality and country,do you know some method to gain the exhaustive information of a place?thanks